# Sold individually option for every WooCommerce product variable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a variable product, My variable product has 2 variables :

1. Variable 1 : Sold individually = No
2. Variable 2 : Sold individually = Yes

Is it possible that there is a Sold individually option for each variable? Now there is only one Sold individually option that includes both variables.

https://imgur.com/a/1Rn33Si

Answer (score 1):

the Sold individually option applies to the whole product, not individual variations. so It's not possible to have separate the options for each variation.

You could hook `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` filter and check the cart items to make sure only one quantity of the specific variations is added.

```
function custom_sold_individually_validation($passed, $product_id, $quantity) {
    if (get_post_type($product_id) === 'product_variation' && get_post_meta($product_id, '_sold_individually', true) === 'yes') 
    {

        $cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart();

        foreach ($cart_items as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
            // Check if the variation is already in the cart
            if ($cart_item['variation_id'] === $product_id) {
                // Display an error message
                wc_add_notice(__('Only one quantity allowed to current variation'), error');
                $passed = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $passed;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'custom_sold_individually_validation', 10, 3);
```